# Applying 3d transformation to cuboid

Tags: matlab, 3d, affinetransform

[image]I have the 8 vertices of a cuboid (red points)(XYZvox) with known distance in millimetres (vox to mm) between each vertex which I transform in 3d space using the 4d transformation matrix (M). I am really struggling to work out the new voxel to millimetre conversion for the transformed vertices. How can I work this out? I feel it should be relatively straightforward:

```
XYZvox =[ 1     1     1     1   409   409   409   409
     1     1   389   389     1     1   389   389
     1   162     1   162     1   162     1   162]

M =[0.0337    0.0958   -0.9616   -2.5360
    0.3706    0.0107    0.1012 -150.2009
    0.0201   -0.3571   -0.2550 -231.0513
         0         0         0    1.0000]

for i=1:8
    poi1=XYZvox(:,i);
    poi2=[XYZvox(:,i)];
    poi2(4,1)=1;

    poi_trans=M*poi2;

    poi_trans=poi_trans(1:3);

    scatter3(poi1(1),poi1(2),poi1(3),'red','filled'); xlabel('x'); hold all;
    scatter3(poi_trans(1),poi_trans(2),poi_trans(3),'green','filled'); xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z'); 
end
```

EDIT: The original vertices are the limits of 3d imaging data stack in imager coordinates and the transformed data is in world coordinates. If there were no rotation, only scaling and translation I could work out the new pix/vox->mm conversion but because the volume is also rotated it makes it more difficult

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you try to calculate the new length of each transformed vertice ? But how matlab can know which node is connected to which one ? You need an adjency matrix no ?

Comment: In general, affine transformation does not preserve distances. Therefore, you need to figure out the new distances in terms of px after the transformation. When you know these, I believe the conversion to mm is the same factor.

Comment: What is the meaning of your transformation matrix? As pointed out by Vahe, (relative) distances are not preserved. So, in general, there will not exist one voxel to mm conversion factor.

Comment: As this seems to me rather a math question than a programming one, it may be useful to post it at https://math.stackexchange.com instead (and delete it here).

Comment: Just to clarify the original vertices are the limits of 3d imaging data stack in imager coordinates and the transformed data is in world coordinates. If there were no rotation, only scaling and translation I could work out the new pix/vox->mm conversion but because the volume is also rotated it makes it more difficult...